# Rendering a partial with locals

Tags: ruby, post, locals

I've rendered a partial that also loads the Users latest post in one of the tab panels.

```
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="updates_panel"> 
      <%= render :partial => "pages/update_panel", :locals => { :post => @user.latest_post } %>
      </div>
```

At first the method latest_post was to display the users "Last or Latest Post".

```
def latest_post
  posts.order(:created_at => :desc).first
end
```

But now I realized I need to display all the post in descending order and I cant seem to get this right.

Answer (score 1):

create another method like `latest_posts`,

```
def latest_posts
  posts.order(:created_at => :desc)
end

def latest_post
  latest_posts.first
end
```

And now use this in your partal,

```
<%= render :partial => "pages/update_panel", :locals => { :post => @user.latest_post, :posts => @user.latest_posts } %>
```

Comment: Seems like it would work, but yet under the tab panel I still only display the latest post, not followed by the rest of the post.